# redirect mobile request to different url

Tags: apache, http, mobile

Im trying to redirect the mobile request to different url on my website say abcd.com on the basis of HTTP_USER_AGENT in apache 2.2

I have written the following script in http.conf file in apache conf folder,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.so>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]

    RewriteRule ^$ https://abcd.com/userMaster/rl_login [L,R=302]
</IfModule>
```

pls suggest if im doing anything wrong

Thanks
Praveen

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you skip trying to do it via your `http.conf` file and rather do it with an `.htaccess` file located in the websites root folder.

To achieve this, simply create a text file on your local computer, add the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "alcatel|amoi|android|avantgo|blackberry|benq|cell|cricket|docomo|elaine|htc|iemobile|iphone|ipad|ipaq|ipod|j2me|java|midp|mini|mmp|mobi|motorola|nec-|nokia|palm|panasonic|philips|phone|playbook|sagem|sharp|sie-|silk|smartphone|sony|symbian|t-mobile|telus|up\.browser|up\.link|vodafone|wap|webos|wireless|xda|xoom|zte" [NC]

RewriteRule ^$ https://abcd.com/userMaster/rl_login [L,R=302]
```

And save it as a `.htaccess` file. Then, log into your server with your FTP-client and upload that `.htaccess` file to the root directory of the website.

If you are able to upload files using FTP, then you must be able to add a `.htaccess` file to the server.